# File.Copy method makes file inaccessible

Tags: c#, file-access

I am struggling with this for some time now. I can not access a file after I call File.Copy method. Here is what I tried:

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
FileStream fs = File.Open(destinationFile, FileMode.Open);
```

I am getting UnauthorizedAccessException on the second line. It says: Access to the path ... is denied. I have also tried suggestion stated [here](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2056240439) but that didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is what I found out. If I do this:

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
FileStream fs = File.Open(destinationFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

It doesn't throw exception. The file I am trying to access is read only. So, I tried to remove read only attribute like this:

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(destinationFile);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
FileStream fs = File.Open(destinationFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

And I get the same exception as before. By the way, I checked if I can open file manually and edit it, and I can. Of course, when I uncheck read only check box. I have also checked file attributes in windows explorer while debugging, right after the third line, and the file is no longer read only. Having all that in checked, I don't understand why is the exception being thrown on the fourth line.

Comment: Try putting a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` between the lines to see if it is a timing problem (file might still be locked by the `File.Copy()`

Comment: I tried to make something similar. I created a while loop which should exit if exception is not thrown. But it never exited...

Comment: Have you tried removing the read-only attribute before copying?

Comment: @leppie Yes, right now, for the sourceFile and that worked, but that is not the right way to do it, because the file is supposed to stay read only. I can set it back to read only... But I want to know why is destination file inaccessible, and is it possible to do this without changing source file. Thanks.

Comment: @Vale: Damn, but it's a start :)  What happens when you 'double toggle' read-only (on source or dest)?

Comment: @leppie That actually worked on the destination file! I don't know how you came up with it, but it solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Vale: Educated guess :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's ONLY files copied using `File.Copy` that you can't open, and not every file in the target folder?  And is this a regular NTFS folder, or network share?

If you are running an antivirus or security software, try disabling it.  After a file is created they will often open a file to scan it.

**Update**

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx - `UnauthorizedAccessException` thrown by `File.Open` will not give the message 'Access to the path... is denied'. *(edit: I can't see that message for File.Copy either, so this might be wrong)*

I suspect it is your `File.Copy` that fails with that exception, and you don't have rights to read the source file, or write the target file.  You're probably looking at the highlighted source code line, which shows the next line to be exectued.

So - maybe your copy fails, not the `File.Open` ?

Comment: Problem is, the file does not exist at first, than I copy, and try to access destination file. I am positive that I have all the rights needed, because i am coping it to the desktop.

Comment: Jeez, I don't know how I can make this easier.  Please answer each question, andcheck that you have before clicking Add Comment: 1) Can you open other files in the target folder? 2) Is this a regular NTFS folder, or network share? 3) Have you tried disabling all security software/antivirus?

Comment: Don't know what the fourth yes was for, and you didn't state whether it was an NTFS folder or network share. Nonetheless, I think you're looking at the wrong statement.  Please see updated answer :)

Comment: Your freaking desktop could be a network share, which could help explain the problem.  There's no reason to assume everything is obvious and quickly-answered, clearly you haven't been able to solve your own problem and may have glossed over some detail; solving this kind of thing involves carefully examining the details.

Comment: Did you double-check it wasn't the `File.Copy` failing?

Comment: Yes I did. When I use only File.Copy it copies the file normally.

Answer (score -2):

Try this!

---

```
   private bool CheckFileHasCopied(string FilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                using (File.OpenRead(FilePath))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return CheckFileHasCopied(FilePath);
        }

    }
```

---

```
if (CheckFileHasCopied(destinationFile)) { File.Delete(sourceFile); }
```